# Can I double a pumpkin pie recipe for 10 x 2 inch pan?

Tags: baking

Can I just double the Libby's recipe and bake the pie in a 10 inch by 2 inch pie pan?

Comment: As not all of our users are familiar with the Libbys recipe, could you please edit your post to include it, especially the instructions about pan size and baking time?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the classic Libby's Pumpkin pie recipe (makes one 9-inch pie):

```
1 can (15 oz) canned pumpkin
1-1/2 cups (1 can or 12 fl oz) evaporated milk
3/4 cup granulated sugar
1/2 tsp salt
1 tsp ground cinnamon
1/2 tsp ground ginger
1/4 tsp ground cloves
2 large eggs
1 unbaked 9-inch (4 cup volume) deep dish pie shell

Combine everything but the pie shell, pour the filling into the pie shell.
Bake at 425F for 15 minutes, reduce temperature to 350F and bake 30-40 minutes 
or until knife inserted near center comes out clean.
```

Source: the label on a can of Libby's Pumpkin from my pantry (Instructions paraphrased by me)

The note about the "4 cup volume" of the pie crust gives a helpful hint. This recipe should make about 4 cups of pie filling, so to substitute into a larger pie pan, you will need more filling. Based on moscafj's helpful information that a 10x1.5 inch pie pan has a 6.5 cup capacity, we can do the math to make a substitution.

The larger pan has the capacity for 1.625 times as much filling as the recipe makes. Since the recipe has two eggs in it, it can be easily scaled in increments of half a batch. Half-batch increments will leave you with some leftover pumpkin and evaporated milk, which can be frozen for later use. I have found from experience that this recipe is perfectly good made with regular milk of any fat content, so you could avoid having leftovers by using one can of evaporated milk plus 3/4 cup regular milk. If using all regular milk, bring it up to room temperature or the filling will be cold, which will make the crust underbaked on the bottom.

You can round down and make 1.5 times the recipe, and make a slightly shallower pie. Or round up to 2 times the recipe, and have about 1.5 cups of leftover filling. The leftover filling can be cooked in a smaller pan, with or without crust. Making it without crust is useful if you have gluten-free guests. Be sure to check on it and take it out of the oven earlier than the large pie, or it will burn.

**Ingredients for 1.5 times batch of Libby's Pumpkin Pie** (makes about 6 cups of filling)

```
22.5 oz canned pumpkin (you will need to purchase two 15-oz cans or one 29-oz can)
2-1/4 cups (18 fl oz or one and a half 12-oz cans) evaporated milk
1-1/8 cups (1 cup plus 2 tbsp) granulated sugar
3/4 tsp salt
1-1/2 tsp ground cinnamon
3/4 tsp ground ginger
3/8 tsp ground cloves
3 large eggs
1 unbaked 10-inch pie shell
```

**Ingredients for 2 times batch of Libby's Pumpkin Pie** (makes about 8 cups of filling)

```
2 15-oz cans canned pumpkin OR 1 29-oz can
2 cups (2 cans or 24 fl oz) evaporated milk
1-1/2 cups granulated sugar
1 tsp salt
2 tsp ground cinnamon
1 tsp ground ginger
1/2 tsp ground cloves
4 large eggs
1 unbaked 10-inch pie shell
optional: additional pie crust to fit a smaller pan with 1.5 cup capacity (such as a Gratin dish or small tart pan)
```

Instructions: same as classic recipe, except that the final baking time at 350F will be different. The increased pan width would make it longer, but if the filling is shallower that would make the cook time shorter. Actual bake time will depend on how deep your filling is. Start checking on the pie at around 20 minutes, by jiggling the pan. Once the filling no longer wobbles, start checking with a knife. Expect your first attempt to have many knife slits in it. If you align the knife slits with where the pieces will be sliced, you can pre-slice the *completely cooled* pie and your guests will never know.

Note: The edges of the crust often burn when I make it in even a normal 9-inch size. For a longer bake time, I highly recommend shielding the crust edges with strips of foil or a purpose-made pie crust shield. Remove the shield for the final 5-10 minutes of bake time if it's not adequately browned already.

Answer (score -1):

[This should get you in the ball park.](https://recipeland.com/how-to/baking-pan-dish-volume-guide-332)  While they don't specify a 10x2 pan, they do indicate that a 10x1.5 (25x4 cm) inch pie pan has a capacity of 6.5 cups (1540 ml).

Comment: It might take longer to bake, other than that there are no issues aside from personal preference (size and thickness of a slice, etc.).

Comment: Could you please include/explain the essential parts *within the post*? While interesting, that’s a candidate for link rot... Thanks!

Comment: @Stephie I believe I provided the relevant info.  It is just a list of pans and their capacities.  There are plenty of similar sources on line. I read the initial question as "how much filling will I need for a 10X2 pie pan?"